# HttpClient timeout and CancelationToken don't work

Tags: android, xamarin, httpclient

I recently updated my visual studio from 2017 to 2019. I am using HttpClient implementation as Default. Everything wass working very well in vs2017.
After i update my vs to 2019. Then when i am using httpClient, timeout and Cancelation Token don't work.

Here is my code:

```
var token = cts.Token;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://" + MyIp + ":9090/api/SqlAction/", new StringContent("my data", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), token);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm I haven't tried http, but does https work for a different URL? Also, can you please explain what it mean that they "don't work", what's the output/error message that you get?

Comment: Example when i call CancelationToken. It doesn't stop my PostAsync. It keeps running

Comment: It seems like an issue in your threading. Can you share the code that calls this function and can you share the rest of the function that contains the post ? I’m interested in the async and the await. 
Based on what you have shared, the thread calling this post call will wait for 20 seconds until a response is received or else it will error out. But the other threads will keep going in the app and not wait for this one to finish unless you have coded it like that